# Perturbation of Normal Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, compact-operators, perturbation-theory

Suppose I have a normal operator (not nec self-adjoint) $N$ on a separable Hilbert space. Suppose that I perturb by a compact operator $K$ to get (not nec normal)

$A=N+K$.

The essential spectra of $N$ and $A$ agree. My question is, does the addition of $K$ only cause the possibility of (at most countably many) eigenvalues to appear that can only accumulate at the essential spectrum?

Comment: Can you have uncountably many?

Comment: Hmm not sure. My guess would be no but I don't know how to show that.